# How to uninstall ejabberd from linux instance of aws server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, ejabberd

I had a linux instance on the AWS server and I installed ejabberd 15.06 on it using the following commands:

```
mkdir Downloads
wget -O Downloads/ejabberd-15.06-linux-x86_64-installer.run https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/ejabberd-15.06-linux-x86_64-installer.run
chmod +x Downloads/ejabberd-15.06-linux-x86_64-installer.run
sudo Downloads/ejabberd-15.06-linux-x86_64-installer.run
```

But Now I wanted to uninstall ejabberd from the linux instance and since i am a linux newbie I can't figure out how to do this.

I have already tried the apt-get command but the terminal generates a message that the 'apt-get' command is not found.
In the ejabberd 15.06 directory I have the following stucture

```
backup
bin
conf
database
doc
lib
logs
uninstall(displayed in different color)
uninstall.dat
```

Can anyone guide me over how to get this uninstalled from the linux instance?

Comment: Since you did not use but actually bypass the systems software management system you cannot use it now to uninstall something. Instead of performing such a "wild install" you should have installed a package, then uninstalling would be a breeze now. Instead you have to manually clean up, find out what files were installed where (how ever you do that) and remove them. Hopefully you don't break too much :-(

Comment: but just removing the files(related to ejabberd) would uninstall the ejabberd?

Comment: Yep, though it is (nearly) impossible to clearly find out what files actually got installed. You want to remove the configuration section under `/etc/...` too, it might have created additional files there too. And maybe also some in the control users home folder, some hidden files...

Comment: Ah, before that you want to stop and disable the service. How you do that depends on what Linux distribution you use.

Comment: well mine is just a test project which is not been used by anybody but me at the moment, So does the " disabling the service " means stopping the instance altogether or just disconnecting the users(as there aren't any but me)

Comment: Neither nor. Stopping the service means this: a daemon is an application that is executed permanently in background. That is important for daemons offerin a service (like http servers or jabber daemons), since they already need to run _before_ someone uses them. For that they are registered as "service" at the local system and typically started upon booting or restarted automatically if crashed. That is what you should revers before deleting the files. So the question is: how did you start the daemon?

Comment: I just use the putty client to set up a SSH connection with AWS server that's it. After that i just used the above mentioned four commands. So I didn't start any deamons(sorry if i's mistaken,i am a begginner and have not hard of this)

Comment: Hm, maybe that "installer" provides an "uninstall" feature? Otherwise just remove the files and reboot the instance.

Comment: And you definitely want to learn how to install software on a Linux system in a clean manner. That differs quite a lot from an MS-Windows system as you apparently are used to. And there are _very_ good reasons for the difference, as we can see here.

Comment: yes indeed but I only found this link[https://trinitytuts.com/setup-ejabberd-server-ec2-ubuntu-instance/](https://trinitytuts.com/setup-ejabberd-server-ec2-ubuntu-instance/) in terms of installing ejabberd on linux instance.If you do you know any other way please share otherwise thank you so much for bearing with my naive questions

Comment: THe usual way to install packages on most Linux based systems is to use the software management system and to just select that desired package from the wealth of perfectly prepared packages offered in there. How _exactly_ that works depends, as said above, on the type of Linux system you operate, so the distribution. Can you answer that question?

Comment: I am actually using a linux instace on amazon web server as "Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-4836a428" so it is basically amazon linux

Comment: That apparently us based on RedHat Linux which means that certainly the `apt` utility family is _not_ available. Most likely `yum` is used to access the existing package repositories. There certainly is an ejabberd package offered there. I suggest you start reading the documentation of the system you use. All that is documented.

Comment: ok, thank you for the help.

Comment: hey I found out that the above explained method is also one of the methods explained in ejabberd's documentation to install ejabberd. And ejabberd does not provides a package installation for linux or amazon linux.

Comment: That certainly is correct. But what does that tell you? And I never said that it won't work. I only pointed out why it has huge disadvantages. I doubt the guys behind that software invest a huge amount of time into the question of how to _uninstall_ their software again. You see the issue here?

Comment: even after removing the files manually the ejabberd is not getting installed again. not even with the same steps that I followed before, and points out a error at line 1 as " syntax error near unexpected token `newline'  `<!DOCTYPE html>'" and I have opened and checked the files, they are still the same

Comment: You never said you want to reinstall it before! What _is_ this question about?

Comment: well ejabberd 15.06 does not allow xmpp compliant functions, thus I had to use ejabberd17.03 or higher version. That's all